# Visual Studio not auto-building when I press the debug button

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debug, compile, build

I'm writing code in Visual Studio but whenever I want to test the application and press the green arrow for "Start debugging", Visual Studio does not automatically recompile the active solution for me and I have to manually build the solution then debug it.

Visual Studio used to automatically build before debug and I want this back as contantly having to manually build is a serious pain.

Thanks

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In the Visual Studio settings under **Projects and Solutions**->**Build and Run** change the option **On Run, when projects are out of date:** from *Never Build* to *Always Build*

**Edit:**  Per your comments, open the "Configuration Manager" (in the Debug/Release dropdown) and ensure that the **Build** checkbox is checked for all of the projects you want to build in each of your configurations.

Comment: its not working :(

Comment: Changed the build type to "release" and it worked fine. What are the differences between building for 'Debug' instead of 'release'?

Comment: Did you open the Configuration Manager to make sure that the "Build" checkbox is checked under the debug configuration?

Comment: Ahhh thank you! Thank fixed it! Never even noticed the configuration manager menu item before.

Comment: There is also an option "Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run". If it's set and your dependencies are not "good enough", Studio might skip building some of your projects. Unsetting this option helps.

Comment: The Projects and Solutions tab is found under the Debug->Options and Settings... dialog.

Comment: You know I set it to Prompt to build, and it still auto builds them

Answer (score 13):

- Navigate to Debug > Options and Settings in the VS menu or Tools > Options...
- Go to 'Projects and Solutions' > 'Build and Run' and make sure that the “Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run” box is left unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was missing the config under `Project` -> `Project Dependencies`, which updates the .sln file to ensure correct build order for projects.

Answer (score -1):

Tool --> Options --> Project and Solutions --> "On Run, The project is out of date" never build --> change to Always build. I solved me

Comment: It is unclear as to what you are suggesting

Answer (score -1):

Tool --> Options --> Project and Solutions.

1. Set as Always build / Prompt to Build for "On Run, The project is out of date"
2. Uncheck the check box for "Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run"